# I'm doing a factorial c# program, but after the second attempt, it starts to miscalculate

Tags: c#, factorial

```
int num, i, fatorial = 1;
char resposta;
    
do
{    
    Console.WriteLine("Informe um numero e veja o seu fatorial: ");
    num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    for(i=1; i <= num; i++)
    {
        fatorial *= i;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("O fatorial de "+num+" é "+fatorial);
    Console.WriteLine("Calcular outro número (s/n)?");
    resposta = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
} while(resposta !='n');
```

The first time the works fine, but if a try again, it miscalculates.

Comment: Now's a good time to learn [how to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [to use a debugger](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)  
Step through your code and observe what each line of code does. 
Identify where your program differs from your expectations by comparing these intermediate results with expected results. 
Work backwards from there to narrow down the cause of the problem. 
Then ask a _specific_ question if you are still confused by your code's behavior. It's not okay to dump your code and expect other people to debug it for you.

Comment: Factorial grows *very fast*, `13! > int.MaxValue` and you will have *integer overflow* in this case. Declare `factorial` as a *floating point* value: `double factorial = 1.0;`

Comment: Hint: You need to initialize `fatorial` _every time_ you start calculating a new number's factorial

Comment: Change `for(i=1; i <= num; i++)` to `for(i=2, fatorial=1; i <= num; i++)` as there's no need to multiply by 1.  This will reset "fatorial" each time when the `for` loop starts.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi ok bro, iam begginer here, dont know to much for programming :/

Comment: @Idle_Mind tks, u fix the error <3

Comment: Yeah, lot's of different ways to do it!  =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reset `factorial` each loop, otherwise it holds the value from the last loop.

Add:

```
do
    {    
        factorial = 1; // re-initialize every loop
        Console.WriteLine("Informe um numero e veja o seu fatorial: ");
        num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't reinitialize the `factorial` in the loop, so on the second (and subsequent) iterations, you'll be dragging the previous calculation with you. Reinitialize `factorial = 1` when you reinitialize `num` to the user input and you should be fine.